# Let $x_n$ diverge to $\infty$ and $y_n$ converge to L > 0. Show $x_n y_n$ diverges to $\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can I do this by stating that since $y_n$ is positive,  $x_n y_n$ is a subsequence of $x_n$? Or will I not be able to prove the subsequence diverges either?

Comment: just show that for any $M>0$ there exists $n_0 \in Z$ such that $x_ny_n>M$ for all $n>n_0$

Comment: $\{x_ny_n\}$ is not a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$

Comment: ^ I know that. I was wondering if I could manipulate it into one

Comment: Not really .. take $x_n=n$, and $y_n= e-\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ small, and choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $x_n>M/(L-\epsilon)$ and $|y_n-L|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$. Then $-\epsilon+L<y_n<\epsilon+L$, and so $x_ny_n>M$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use comparison theorems. There exists $n_0 \geq 0$ such that, for all $n\geq n_0$, we have $y_n \geq \frac{L}{2}>0$. This implies that for $n\geq n_0$, $x_ny_n \geq \cdots$